# Why won't objects draw on screen but score does in my Canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a pong game and have used this guide as a template: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/

this is the template my instructor has used and will be having us use once we get that far in the course, I am just working ahead a little.

The scoreboard will draw as it should, and will update with new scores(I added LPaddle.score++ at the end of DrawObjects() to test)

But nothing else will draw, what am I doing wrong here? No syntax errors found.

Here's the .js:

```
//pong VERSION 2 based off of:
//http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/

///////////////////////////
//VARIABLES////////////////
///////////////////////////
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//CONSTANTS and GLOBALS
var MAX_SCORE = 10;

var paused = false;

//style attributes
var ObjectLine = '6';
var fontLine = '1';

context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.lineWidth = ObjectLine;
context.font = '50px Palatino';

//shadow attributes
context.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)';
context.shadowOffsetX = 22;
context.shadowOffsetY = 50;
context.shadowBlur = 20;

//game objects
var LPaddle = {
    speed: 200,
    x:canvas.width/20,
    y: canvas.height/20,
    score: 0,
    scoreX: canvas.width/7,
    scoreY: canvas.height/1.01
};

var RPaddle = {
    speed: 200,
    x:canvas.width/1.1,
    y: canvas.height/20,
    score: 0,
    scoreX: canvas.width/1.2,
    scoreY: canvas.height/1.01,
    //sets to get player input or use AI
    isHuman: true
};

var Ball = {
    speed: 200,
    x:canvas.width/20,
    y: canvas.height/20,
    r: canvas.width/50,
    SA: 0,
    EA: 260
};

var Boundaries = {

};

///////////////////////////
///////FUNCTIONS///////////
///////////////////////////

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);


//reset game on win OR PLAYER INPUT
var reset = function() {

};


// Update game objects
var updatePaddles = function(modifier) {
    //play/pause game
    if (32 in keysDown) {
        paused = !(paused);
    }
    //is player object within boundaries?
    if (LPaddle.y > 0 && LPaddle.y < (canvas.height - LPaddle.height)) {
        if (65 in keysDown) { // Player holding a its 65keycode or 97ascii
            LPaddle.y -= LPaddle.speed * modifier;
        }

        if (90 in keysDown) { // Player holding z its 90key or 122ascii
            LPaddle.y += LPaddle.speed * modifier;
        }
    }

        //check right player input if 2player
        if (RPaddle.isHuman) {
            //is player within boundaries?
            if (RPaddle.y > 0 && RPaddle.y < (canvas.height - RPaddle.height)) {
                if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
                    RPaddle.y -= RPaddle.speed * modifier;
                }

                if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
                    RPaddle.y += RPaddle.speed * modifier;
                }
            }
        }


};


// Draw individual objects
var ClearScreen = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

var DrawPaddle = function(x, y, width, height) {
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)';
    context.lineWidth = ObjectLine;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x, y, width, height);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
};

var DrawBall = function(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
};

var DrawScoreBoard = function(lX, rX, y, LPScore, RPScore) {
    context.shadowColor = undefined;
    context.lineWidth = fontLine;
    context.strokeText(LPScore,lX,y);
    context.strokeText(RPScore,rX,y);
};

//DRAW ALL OBJECTS
var DrawObjects = function() {
    ClearScreen();
    DrawPaddle(LPaddle.x, LPaddle.y, LPaddle.width, LPaddle.height);
    DrawPaddle(RPaddle.x, RPaddle.y, RPaddle.width, RPaddle.height);
    DrawBall(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.radius, Ball.SA, Ball.EA);
    DrawScoreBoard(LPaddle.scoreX,RPaddle.scoreX,LPaddle.scoreY,LPaddle.score,RPaddle.score);
};


//MAIN GAME LOOP FXN
// The main game loop
var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    updatePaddles(delta / 1000);

    DrawObjects();
    then = now;

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

here's the .html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JamesG WebDesign</title>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

<style>
body {
    background-color: salmon;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
#toMain {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    font-size: 150%;
}
#canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: thin inset #aaaaaa;
}

#ResetAboveCanvas {
            margin: 20px 0px 20px 450px;
        }
#menu {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 0px 20px 10px 10px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            color: #eeeeee;
            font-family: Droid Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;
            -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;

            display: none;
         }
#menu h2 {
            font-weight: normal;
         }

         #menu .title {
            font-size: 2em;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8);
         }

         #menu a:hover {
            color: yellow;
         }

         #menu a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #cccccc;
            font-size: 3.5em;
         }

         #menu p {
            margin: 10px;
            color: rgba(65, 65, 220, 1.0);
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: Palatino, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>James Gossling Multimedia for Web Design Spring 2018 PONG v2</h2>

<p><strong>Press SPACE to Play/Pause.  Left Paddle use A/Z to move Up/Down.  Right Paddle use UP/DOWN to move Up/Down</strong>
</p>

<div id='ResetAboveCanvas'>
    <input type='button' id='resetButton' value='Reset Game.'/>
</div>

<div id='menu'>
    <h2 class='title'>Pong</h2>
    <p>One hundred balls bouncing</p>
    <a id='startButton'>Restart Game</a>
</div>

<canvas id='canvas' width='800' height='600'>
Canvas not supported
</canvas>

<script src='PONGV2.js'></script>

<br>
<div id="toMain">
<a href="http://webstudentwork.com/jgossling/MMWD/index.html">Back to Main</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was just a careless mistake:  I used LPaddle.width and .height but didn't define them in the paddle objects yet, now to get the ball moving!